# Window.resize on Vue cant compiled

Tags: vue.js

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code?
I copied a pure HTML from this site. The window resize is highlighted red as wrong syntax; I don't know why. Please help me to fix this… still a beginner of Vue.js. Been learning the lifecycle of Vue, but still no help http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/demo/ go to the gamev2

```
<template>
  <div id="about">
    <div id="nav">
        <ul class="nav-atas">
        <li class="li nav-atas col-md-6"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="li nav-atas col-md-6"><a class="active" href="/jobs">Jobs</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
      <ol class="breadcrumb helo">
      <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a style="color:red" href="#">Tokodistributor Career</a></li>
      <li class="breadcrumb-item" aria-current="page">Jobs</li>
      </ol>
    </nav>
    <div class="titel">
      <h1>Find Your Dream Jobs Here at Tokodistributor</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
            <form id="form-game_v2" name="form-game_v2">
              <div class="typeahead__container">
                  <div class="typeahead__field">
                      <div class="typeahead__query">
                          <input class="js-typeahead-game_v2" name="game_v2[query]" type="search" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off">
                      </div>
                      <div class="typeahead__button">
                          <button type="submit">
                              <i class="typeahead__search-icon"></i>
                          </button>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </form>
          <div class="tombolsearch col-md-4">
              <button class="btn btn-danger">
              Search
              </button>
              <button class="btn btn-success">
              View All Jobs
              </button>
          </div>
          <div class="container kerja">
            <h1>Bagaimana Cara Kerja Tokodistributor????</h1>
            <br>  
            <h4>Di Tokodistributor Kami Melayani Supplier,Pembeli Dan Pedagang dari segala penjuru Indonesia</h4>
            <br>
            <img id="gambar1" src="../assets/image/howitworks.png"/>
            </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
require('@/assets/v2/scss/styles.scss')
require('@/assets/v2/scss/Jobs.scss')
require('@/assets/js/cobacoba.js')
export default{
window.onresize = function(event) {
    if ($('#form-game_v2').find('> .typeahead__container.backdrop')) {
        $('#form-game_v2').find('.typeahead__list').css('max-height', $(window).height() - 200 + "px")
    }
} 
$.typeahead({
    input: '.js-typeahead-game_v2',
    minLength: 1,
    maxItem: false,
    highlight: false,
    hint: true,
    group: true,
    maxItemPerGroup: 16,
    backdrop: {
        "background-color": "#fff"
    },
    backdropOnFocus: true,
    cache: "sessionStorage",
    compression: true,
    cancelButton: false,
    template: function () {
      return '<span class="ui blue small label">{{display}}</span>';
    },
    source: {
        game: {
            href: "http://www.gamer-hub.com/game/{{id}}/{{display|slugify}}/",
            template: function (query, item) {
                return '<img src="http://cdn.gamer-hub.com/images/' + this.helper.slugify.call(this, item.display) + '.jpg">' +
                    '<span class="title">{{display}}</span>';
            },
            ajax: {
                url: "http://www.gamer-hub.com/game/list.json",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                path: "data"
            }
        },
        tag: {
            href: "http://www.gamer-hub.com/tag/{{id}}/{{display|slugify}}/",
            ajax: {
                url: "http://www.gamer-hub.com/tag/list.json",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                path: "data"
            }
        },
        category: {
            href: "http://www.gamer-hub.com/category/{{id}}/{{display|slugify}}/",
            ajax: {
                url: "http://www.gamer-hub.com/category/list.json",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                path: "data"
            }
        }
    },
    callback: {
        onShowLayout: function (node, query) {
            node.attr('placeholder', 'Search for a Game ...');
            node.closest('form').find('.typeahead__list').css('max-height', $(window).height() - 200 + "px");
        },
        onHideLayout: function (node, query) {
            node.attr('placeholder', 'Search');
        },
        onLayoutBuiltBefore: function (node, query, result, resultHtmlList) {
            resultHtmlList.find('li[data-search-group="game"]').remove();
            return resultHtmlList;
        },
        onClickAfter: function (node, a, item, event) {

            event.preventDefault();

            var r = confirm("You will be redirected to:\n" + item.href + "\n\nContinue?");
            if (r == true) {
                window.open(item.href);
            }

        }
    }
})
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Comment: Your code has absolutely nothing to do with Vue.js. You just picked a standard `.vue` component structure, deleted all the relevant parts and replaced them with code done the way you did before you tried Vue. That won't work, **at all**. `MVVM` like Vue.js implements cannot work without a model. Your code has none.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is not with your `window.resize`. It's with the `export`. You are saying you want to export an object, but you don't provide an object.

So you want to put your code outside the export, and only put in the export what you actually want to make available elsewhere.

More on export: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Comment: Tried to put all the code outside the export , the result is the webpage didnt show anything at all